# Generating sequential alphanumeric numbers on ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, alphanumeric

I want to generate the Following sequence of *alphanumeric* `string` in ASP.net C#.

**AA000 
AA001
... 
AA999 
AB000 
AB001 
... 
AZ999
BA000
BA001
... 
ZZ999 "**

Comment: Any effort so far? Please read [FAQ] and [ask] couple of times..

Comment: How is this specifically related to ASP.NET?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like that (*Linq*):

```
var source = Enumerable
               .Range(0, 1000 * 26 * 26)
               .Select(x => ((Char) ((x / 1000) / 26 + 'A')).ToString() +
                            ((Char) ((x / 1000) % 26 + 'A')).ToString() +
                             (x % 1000).ToString("000"));
```

...

```
foreach(String item in source) {
...
}
```

To see the whole sequence (e.g. for debugging etc):

```
// AA000 AA001 AA002 ... AA999 AB000 ... AZ999 BA000 ... ZZ999
MyTextBox.Text = String.Join(" ", source);
```